# ReactiveMongoRepository instance is not found on Webflux handler class

Tags: spring-webflux

I am using Spring Boot WebFlux handler functions and route functions with MongoDB. Below is my ReactiveMongoRepository interface and handler classes.

### ReactiveMongoRepository interface

```
public interface UserReactiveMongoRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<User, String> {

    Mono<User> findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);
    Mono<User> findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);  
    Mono<User> findById(@Param("id") Long id);
    Mono<Void> saveUser(Mono<User> monoUser);
}
```

### UserHandler class

```
@Component
public class UserHandler {

    
    private UserReactiveMongoRepository userRepository;
    
    public UserHandler() { }
    
    @Autowired
    public UserHandler(@NonNull UserReactiveMongoRepository userRepository) { 
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }
```

But userRepository instance is not generated on handler component class. I think this error seems to be simple. How can I fix it?

Comment: I added "spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive" dependency on pox.xml. And It works without errors.

Comment: can you please answer your own question if the problem is solved?

Answer (score 0):

I missed  "spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive" dependency on pom.xml. So I added that dependency. And It works without errors.